# Setting up SSL on Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I'm trying to configure Tomcat 8 on Windows for SSL.

I've followed the instructions here:

https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-ssl

so, I've created the a keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -alias Procon -keyalg RSA -keystore $TOMCAT_HOME\Keystore
```

and a CSR:

```
keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias Procon -file cert.csr -keystore $TOMCAT_HOME\Keystore
```

and I've had the root file and new cert back from the provider and installed them in the keystore:

```
keytool -import -alias rootca -keystore $TOMCAT_HOME\Keystore -trustcacerts -file root.txt

keytool -import -alias inter -keystore $TOMCAT_HOME\Keystore -file newssl.txt
```

Then in Tomcat's serverl.xml I've uncommented and updated:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0_Tomcat8(Procon)\Keystore" 
               keystorePass="..."
               keyAlias="inter"
               />
```

and restarted, but when I go to:

```
https://<host>:8443
```

I just get a timeout and I'm stumped. No one on stackoverflow appears to have had this particular issue. Port 8080 is still working as it should.

I'm also a bit confused about the other connectors appearing to redirect to 8443:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

 <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: I'm wondering about these redirectPorts too, but that's the default configuration and not the cause of your problem.

Comment: Have you considered following the *Tomcat* documentation?

Comment: Most CAs return a root cert, *at least one chain cert*, and a server/entity/leaf cert; which is your `newssl.crt`? If it is the leaf cert, it must be importcert'ed *to the alias containing the privatekey* which according to your post is `Procon` not `inter`. In particular, `keytool` must have said `Certificate **reply** was **installed**` **NOT** `Certificate was **added**`. Assuming that, check the tomcat log(s?), use `netstat` or similar to check tomcat is actually listening on 8443, and if so check your network.

Comment: I am having the same problem, and I have followed the tomcat 8 instructions

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a key with the alis `tomcat` instead of `Procon`.

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA...
```

And don't forget to use the *same password* for the keystore as for the key!